# Is it possible to implement a context manager to handle tensor transfer to cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, contextmanager

I am writing a custom implementation of CNN in PyTorch and I need to run the computation on GPU.

I don't use torch NN modules, I define my own layers, where I define my own forward and backprop passes. For convolutions I am using `conv2d` from `torch.nn.functional`.

To run multiplications on GPU I need to set the device to `cuda`.
But writing something like

```
A = torch.randn(1, 10).cuda()
B = torch.randn(10, 20).cuda()

C = A @ B # matrix multiplication
```

seems repetitive to me, because I need to call `cuda()` or `to(device)` on every input tensor.

Is there a way to use something like:

```
# hypothetical context manager 
with torch.use_cuda(): # all tensors used in this context would automatically use cuda
    A = torch.randn(1, 10)
    B = torch.randn(10, 20)
C = A @ B # matrix multiplication on cuda
```

So I can just wrap my code in a context or declare a default device so I am not forced to rewrite everything.